# Would serial key from Microsoft Windows 8.1 Professional N fit to not N version?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have one legal copy of: Microsoft Windows 8.1 Professional N. I can download ISO of a not N version of the system from Microsft site.

Can I use my serial to install not N version?

Answer (score 0):

To quote http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows7/products/what-is-windows-7-n-edition

> Windows 7 N editions, available for customers who live in countries that are part of the European Economic Area, Croatia, and Switzerland, have been designed to give you most of the features of Windows 7—with the addition of choice.

This is the same for Windows 8 (I couldn't find a page that specifically mentioned it), it is **not** licensed separately to *non-N versions* so a *non-N version* should activate fine using the OEM key supplied with the *N version* **AS LONG AS** the version of the software (home, pro, ultimate etc.) is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have a license for Windows 8 Pro, and I just tried to install Windows 8 Pro N (I wanted less bloat).

But when the time came to enter my key it would not allow it. I'm sure it would be the same the other way round then.

Pity.